# How to create dialog which will be full in horizontal dimension

Tags: android, layout, dialog

When I use in layout, which specifies this dialog `android:layout_width="match_parent"` I get this dialog:

[image: small dialog]

I need dialog which will be wider. Any ideas?

Comment: post your xml layout code & try fill parent value instead of match parent

Comment: @rajpara `fill_parent` and `match_parent` do *exactly* the same thing (both are constants of value `-1`)

Answer (score 122, accepted):

You can do that by grabbing the `Window` object that the dialog uses, and resetting the width. Here's a simple example:

```
//show the dialog first
AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        .setTitle("Test Dialog")
        .setMessage("This should expand to the full width")
        .show();
//Grab the window of the dialog, and change the width
WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
Window window = dialog.getWindow();
lp.copyFrom(window.getAttributes());
//This makes the dialog take up the full width
lp.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
lp.height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
window.setAttributes(lp);
```

Here's the end result. Note that there's a lot more styling you can do to the dialog if you need to fine tune things (like change the background, etc). When I've had to do this in the past, I usually use this method, and customize the layout used in the dialog with `setView()` on the builder class.

[image: example]

Comment: Just keep in mind that this might look strange on a large screen, like a tablet for example.

Comment: What if my class extends Application and i want to call alertdialog in that?

Comment: If using a DialogFragment the setting must be done in the `onStart` method, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23990726/how-to-make-dialogfragment-width-to-fill-parent/26207535

Comment: Setting the width to MATCH_PARENT does not completely stretch the dialog to the edges of the screen. There is a background to the window that has a bit of width, but is just set to transparent. I'd like to make the actual content area reach the edges of the screen.

Comment: one question: why is this such a damn pain-in-the-ass to do in the first place? If the outer layout of the XML states "match_parent" then it should be exactly THAT ! damn it, Google.

Comment: @h_k You can remove those edges calling `dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));`

Comment: A supplyment is `window.setAttributes(lp);` should place after `dialog.show();`, or it won't work.

Answer (score 4):

Another way to fix this is to use:

```
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
```

instead of:

```
import android.app.AlertDialog;
```

Comment: The simplest, quickest, and best solution. This should be the accepted answer.