# Full width Dialog

Tags: android, android-dialog

I what the Dialog to cover up the whole screen width.

**Hence:**

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
LayoutParams params = dialog.getWindow().getAttributes();
params.height = LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
params.width = LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
dialog.getWindow().setAttributes(params);
```

But the result is:

[image]

> Skip is a button in a parent layout (MATCH_PARENT as width and height
>   and 10dp padding and orange background).

Even in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11613825/how-to-create-dialog-which-will-be-full-in-horizontal-dimension#answer-11614063) the final result has some gaps on sides.

Is there a way to cover the whole screen width without any gaps?

Comment: getWindow().setLayout(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT); will this help ?

Comment: Its the same. There are still gaps

Comment: try setting params.x to some negative value

Comment: Did you find a solution for it? Please share if so

Comment: @LucasJota `dialog.getWindow().setLayout(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT)` after `dialog.setContentView(view)` worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

The solution that worked for me was the following:

Grab the device dimensions using:

```
WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
Point size = new Point();
display.getSize(size);
```

Then set the width of the dialog to the screen width

```
params.width = size.x;
```