# How to make DialogFragment width to Fill_Parent

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-dialogfragment

I am working on an android application where I am using `DialogFragment` to display the dialog but its width is very small. How I can make this width to `fill_parent` to it ?

```
public class AddNoteDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

    public AddNoteDialogFragment() {
        // Empty constructor required for DialogFragment
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        getDialog().setTitle(getString(R.string.app_name));
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_add_note_dialog,
                container);

        return view;
    }


    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Dialog dialog = super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);

        // request a window without the title
        dialog.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        return dialog;
    }
}
```

fragment_add_note_dialog.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/addNoteEditText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:hint="@string/clock_enter_add_note"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
        android:inputType="textCapSentences|textMultiLine"
        android:lines="5" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/submit"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/login_button"
        android:text="@string/submit_button"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: Actually, the exact same layout using RelativeLayout is displaying very well. I don't explain that though...

Comment: **Try this answer - Kotlin(2022)** ----------
[https://stackoverflow.com/a/72570746/8774798](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72570746/8774798)

Answer (score 180):

This is the solution I figured out to handle this issue:

```
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Dialog dialog = super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);    
    dialog.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    return dialog;
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    Dialog dialog = getDialog();
    if (dialog != null) {
       dialog.getWindow().setLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
       dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
    }
}
```

Edit:

You can use the code below in `onCrateView` method of Fragment before return the inflated view.

```
getDialog().getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
getDialog().getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
```

Comment: You can just call `dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(null);`

Comment: if it's setted to null, it doesn't be transparent... only black, on 4.0.4

Comment: For me, it works if I put `getDialog.getWindow().setLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);` in the DialogFragment's `onResume()` method. It did not work on the `onCreateView()` method.  I modified the answer slightly from `dialog` to `getDialog()`.

Comment: `setLayout` in the `onStart` method works perfectly. Thanks.

Answer (score 98):

Have you tried using the answer of Elvis from [How to make an alert dialog fill 90% of screen size](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8991860/2413303)?

It is the following:

```
dialog.getWindow().setLayout(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
```

---

**Update:**

Above code should be added inside `onStart()` method of the `DialogFragment`.

Comment: Which LayoutParams did you import?

Comment: @ymerdrengene Very good question actually. Try `WindowManager.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT`.

Comment: @ymerdrengene although technically, they are all just inheriting this value from `ViewGroup.LayoutParams`, so it works perfectly fine either way.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce Ah okay, I imported the first suggestion and it works :D Thank you!

Comment: As mentioned here http://stackoverflow.com/a/15279400/1641882 I would suggest moving this code to `onCreateDialog`

Comment: import android.view.WindowManager;

Comment: This single line does the trick!! Nice!

Answer (score 68):

This is worked for me

Create your custom style :

```
   <style name="DialogStyle" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowMinWidthMajor">97%</item>
    <item name="android:windowMinWidthMinor">97%</item>
   </style>
```

You can also try use the right parent to match your other dialogs. for example `parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dialog"` and so on.

Use this style in your dialog

```
public class MessageDialog extends DialogFragment {

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_TITLE, R.style.DialogStyle);
}

// your code 
}
```

Comment: beautiful solution with <item name="android:windowBackground">@null</item>.

Comment: take care to use the right parent to match your other dialogs. on my case it was ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dialog

Answer (score 40):

For me, it worked when I replaced the LinearLayout parent of the layout inflated in onCreateView by RelativeLayout. No other code change required.

Comment: Typical, always the most unpopular answer on stack overflow solves my problem. Thanks

Comment: I liked this answer very much but don't the reason why it works for relative layout only?

Answer (score 22):

```
    <!-- A blank view to force the layout to be full-width -->
    <View
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal" />
```

in the top of my dialog layout did the trick.

Comment: This works for me, and I like that it doesn't require us to add anything extra in code, but I'm wondering _why_ it works...

Comment: Incredibly, this is the only thing that worked for me. Custom style did not.

Comment: perfect. need something simple like this.

Comment: What was your root layout?

Answer (score 20):

```
public class FullWidthDialogFragment extends AppCompatDialogFragment {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NORMAL, R.style.Theme_AppCompat_Light_Dialog_Alert);
    }
}
```

and if you want much more flexibility can  extend AppCompat_Dialog_Alert and custom attributes

Answer (score 18):

Based on other solutions, I have created my own.

```
<style name="AppTheme.Dialog.Custom" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowMinWidthMajor">100%</item>
    <item name="android:windowMinWidthMinor">100%</item>
</style>
```

```
abstract class BaseDialogFragment : DialogFragment() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_TITLE, R.style.AppTheme_Dialog_Custom)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 12):

In my case I also used the following approach:

```
    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        getDialog().getWindow().setLayout(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.dialog_height));
    }
}
```

But there were **still small gaps** between left and right edges of the dialog and the screen edges on some Lollipop+ devices (e.g. Nexus 9).

It was not obvious but finally I figured out that to make it **full width** across all the devices and platforms **window background** should be specified inside *styles.xml* like the following:

```
<style name="Dialog.NoTitle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:padding">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/window_bg</item>
</style>
```

And of course this style needs to be used when we create the dialog like the following:

```
    public static DialogFragment createNoTitleDlg() {
        DialogFragment frag = new Some_Dialog_Frag();
        frag.setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_TITLE, R.style.Dialog_NoTitle);
        return frag;
}
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer! Saved me so much of time! The window background did the trick.

Answer (score 12):

I want clarify this. Both the ways are right, **But with different DialogFragment**.

### Using `android.app.DialogFragment`

```
@Override
public void onStart()
{
    super.onStart();
    Dialog dialog = getDialog();
    if (dialog != null)
    {
        int width = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
        int height = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
        dialog.getWindow().setLayout(width, height);
    }
}
```

### Using `android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment`

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NORMAL, android.R.style.Theme_Black_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen);
}
```

Comment: Basically I needed full width and this worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

This works for me perfectly.

```
android:minWidth="300dp"
```

Through this you can give the width to dialog Fragment.

Answer (score 2):

User AlertDialog.Builder inside your DialogFragment. Add it in `onCreateDialog` method like this. And in `onCreateView` do nothing.

```
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.gf_confirm_order_timeout_dialog, null);
    final Bundle args = getArguments();
    String message = args.getString(GfConstant.EXTRA_DATA);
    TextView txtMessage = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_message);
    txtMessage.setText(message);

    view.findViewById(R.id.btn_confirm).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            if (mListener != null)
            {
                mListener.onDialogConfirmOK();
            }
        }
    });
    builder.setView(view);
    Dialog dialog = builder.create();
    dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
    dialog.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    return dialog;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a custom style in your style.xml file. Just copy paste this code into your style.xml file

```
<style name="CustomDialog" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light" >
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
</style>
```

Then in the createDialog method of your DialogFragment, create the dialog object by the code

```
 dialog = new Dialog(getActivity(), R.style.CustomDialog);
```

Comment: I had to add the following to the style to make it work for me: 

        <item name="android:windowMinWidthMajor">100%</item>
        <item name="android:windowMinWidthMinor">100%</item>

Answer (score 2):

This is how i solved when i faced this issue. Try this.

in your DialogFragment's onActivityCreated, Add this code according to your need....

```
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        myview=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_insurance_detail, container, false);
        intitviews();
        return myview;
    }
    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle arg0) {
        super.onActivityCreated(arg0);
        getDialog().getWindow().getAttributes().windowAnimations = R.style.DialogAnimation;
        getDialog().getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
        getDialog().getWindow().setLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        getDialog().getWindow().setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

option 1. add following code in oncreate in activity

```
 getDialog().getWindow()
         .setLayout(WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
```

or you can Create a custom style for Dialog

```
<style name="CustomDialog" parent="AppTheme" >
  <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
  <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
  <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
  <item name="android:windowCloseOnTouchOutside">true</item>
</style>


 then use that style in dialog fragment


@Override public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NORMAL, R.style.CustomDialog);
}

@Override public void onStart() {
  super.onStart();
  getDialog().getWindow()
    .setLayout(WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
}

SampleDialogFragment sampleDialogFragment = new SampleDialogFragment();
SampleDialogFragment.show(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), "sometag");
```

OR you try the following code in style will help you

```
<item name="android:windowBackground">@null</item>
```

Solution 2: dialog.window.setLayout

```
class TestDialog : DialogFragment() {

    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()

        dialog?.window?.setLayout(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT)
    }

}
```

Comment: Only solution 2 is working (`dialog.window.setLayout`)

Answer (score 2):

I end up with a decent solution for this issue.

Based in @Владислав-Стариков answer.

First you need to create Theme overlay where AppTheme is your main theme so it will apply the same attributes in your main theme like the following:

```
  <style name="AppTheme.DialogOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowMinWidthMajor">50%</item>
    <item name="android:windowMinWidthMinor">90%</item>
  </style>
```

Then override **onCreate** in your **DialogFragment** class

```
  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setStyle(STYLE_NORMAL, R.style.AppTheme_DialogOverlay)
  }
```

Comment: Good answer. 

You can also override `getTheme()` and pass the theme id to get the same result, instead of overriding`onCreate()` and using `setStyle()`.
 
`override fun getTheme() = R.style.AppTheme_DialogOverlay`

Answer (score 1):

use this in onCreateView method of DialogFragment

```
Display display = getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
int width = display.getWidth();
int px = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, **220**, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
getDialog().getWindow().setLayout(width,px);
```

**220** is dialog fragment height, change it as u wish

Answer (score 1):

in your layout root, set android:minWidth to a very large value
e.g

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:minWidth="9999999dp">

   ...

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried multiple answers listed above; they didn't work for me.
This is the solution to my issue:

In `DialogFragment()`, add the codes below:

```
override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    if (showsDialog) {
        val width = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
        val height = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
        dialog?.window?.apply {
            setBackgroundDrawable(ColorDrawable(Color.WHITE))
            attributes.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM
            setLayout(width, height)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A clearer and more flexible approach is to set a percentage of the screen's width. Can do the same for the height and it's easy to change.

```
override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    dialog?.window?.let { window ->
        val params: ViewGroup.LayoutParams = window.attributes
        params.width = context?.getScreenSize(false)?.x?.times(0.9)?.toInt()
            ?: ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
        params.height = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
        window.attributes = params as WindowManager.LayoutParams
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me,

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NORMAL, android.R.style.Theme_Material_Dialog_NoActionBar_MinWidth);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

It goes full width, if `ConstraintLayout` is used as a root layout, without any additional code.

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```