# android set width and height of dialog fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I want to set the width and height of dialog fragment. Have seen many examples but they do it in Java file. I want do it in xml file without hardcoding the values. How can I achieve this?

Comment: parent layout layout_width, layout_height

Answer (score 0):

Without hardcoding this might be the solution, If the fragment is in a linear layout then this is enough

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    ... />
```

Comment: I dont want it full screen...I want to set it to my custom height and width

Comment: custom means you set the width and height so set width and height as desired with `dp` values.

Comment: But  Idont want to hardcore it... Can i do something with margin values?

Comment: Margin and padding will affect from the height and width. What exact height spec do you want ?

Comment: The height of the dialog fragment... I have 1 more doubt... Currently in the dialog fragment I have an edit text. When I click on it, I want the fragment to resize itself instead of going up the screen

Comment: You mean when someone clicks the edidtext you want to resize the dialog fragment ?

Comment: Yes currently I have a dialog fragment as per the image in the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26974068/how-to-set-the-width-of-a-dialogfragment-in-percentage . Instead of button "Los", I have an edit text and my dialog fragment height is still more. When I click on edit text, the key board pops up and my entire top part of dialog fragment moves up. I need to prevent this