# DialogFragment always wraps i'ts content and does not keep the min width as a alertdialog

Tags: android, dialog, android-alertdialog, dialogfragment

MyCustomDialogFragment always wraps it's content and does not keep the min width like a Alertdialog. How can I set the width to respond as a standard Android dialog ?

This is the function I call to display the dialog:

```
      private void displayDialogEdit(String title, String edit,
MyCustomEditDialog.MyCustomEditDialogListener listener, boolean onlyNumbers){
            MyCustomEditDialog dialog = MyCustomEditDialog.newInstance(title, edit, onlyNumbers);
            dialog.setInterface(listener);
            dialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "edit");
        }
```

This is MyCustomDialogFragment.

```
public class MyCustomEditDialog extends DialogFragment {

    private MyCustomEditDialog.MyCustomEditDialogListener mInterface;

    public static MyCustomEditDialog newInstance(String title, String editText, boolean onlyNumbers){
        MyCustomEditDialog dialog = new MyCustomEditDialog();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString("title", title);
        args.putString("edit", editText);
        args.putBoolean("numbers", onlyNumbers);
        dialog.setArguments(args);
        return dialog;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_edit_dialog, container);

        getDialog().getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

//        Bundle args = getArguments();
//
//        boolean numbers = args.getBoolean("numbers");
//
//        TextView txt = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.title);
//        txt.setText(args.getString("title"));
//
//        final EditText edit = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.editText);
//        edit.setText(args.getString("edit"));
//
//        if (numbers) edit.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
//
//        Button btn = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.save);
//
//        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
//            @Override public void onClick(View view) {
//                if (mInterface!=null) mInterface.customDialogOnClick(edit.getText().toString());
//            }
//        });
//
//        setCancelable(true);

        return v;
    }

    public void setInterface(MyCustomEditDialog.MyCustomEditDialogListener listener){
        this.mInterface = listener;
    }


    public interface MyCustomEditDialogListener {
        void customDialogOnClick(String result);
    }

}
```

This is my layout for the custom dialog

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingStart="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingEnd="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:textColor="@color/blue_dark"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:inputType="text"
        />

    <Button
        style="@style/btnBasic.blue"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/save"
        android:id="@+id/save" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Sample of result:

[image: dialog small]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make DialogFragment width to Fill\_Parent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23990726/how-to-make-dialogfragment-width-to-fill-parent)

Comment: I don't wont to fill the screen just respond as a alertdialog size, the best thing might be to change dialogfragment to alertdialog with custom view

Answer (score 3):

Found a simple solution to keep the standard with of a alertDialog on a fragmentDialog.

Override the onCreate method from the fragment with this:

```
 @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_TITLE, android.R.style.Theme_Material_Light_Dialog_Alert);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try these method**

- **set layout width and height in code by**

  ```
  alertDialog.getWindow().setLayout(600, 400);
  ```
- **set on your main theme for dialog**

  ```
  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
  ```

  **Theme**

  ```
   <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
  <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
  <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
  <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
  <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
  <item name="android:dialogTheme">@style/dialog_light</item>



  </style>


  <style name="dialog_light" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
  <item name="@android:windowBackground">@color/whitegrey</item>
  <item name="@android:textColor">@color/black</item>
  </style>
  ```
- **Set theme In code Also like that**

  ```
  new AlertDialog.Builder(
  new ContextThemeWrapper(context, android.R.style.Theme_Dialog))
  ```

Answer (score 1):

I came across this issue today and I found an easy solution: you can override the `getTheme()` method from `DialogFragment` and return `R.style.Theme_AppCompat_Light_Dialog_Alert` from it (or any other theme you want, I used the `AppCompat` one so this will work in older versions of Android).

Example code in Kotlin:

```
class ExampleDialog : DialogFragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.example_dialog, container, false)
    }

    override fun getTheme(): Int {
        return R.style.Theme_AppCompat_Light_Dialog_Alert
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

onViewCreated write this code:

```
dialog?.window?.apply {
            setLayout(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
            )
        }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).